# How to read dictionary with child

Tags: iphone

Help me in reading this dictionary: (its an NSDictionary generated from XMLData)

```
Menus = {

    Table1 = {
        Phone = {
            text = "\n    (404) 371-1466";
        };

        text = "\n  ";
    };
        text = "\n";
    };
}
```

Comment: What are you asking? How to read it from a file? Into some particular structure? Where's it from? Who made it?

Comment: Its in NSDictionary, I generated it from XML data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you the phone number, for example:

```
NSString *phoneNum = [[[[dict objectForKey:@"Menus"] objectForKey:@"Table1"] 
                         objectForKey:@"Phone"] objectForKey:@"text"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have one item in the dictionary - "Menus".

That single item is a dictionary, with two items - "Table 1" and "text".  "Table 1" is a dictionary, "text" is an NSString.

Inside "Table 1", you have two items - "Phone" and "text".  At this point, I think you can see the pattern...

Comment: That I can figure out too, I have never used NSDictionary before..so my question is how to access those items?